# Deleting a row from sqlite based on its position

Tags: android, database

I.m using this query to delete the row at nth position. Here in my code id is my column name and id1 is the position from which i want to delete.

I'm unable to delete anything from the database. Please help

Query I'm using is:
`db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM fly WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM fly LIMIT 1 OFFSET "+id1+")",null);`

Comment: Use your delete query like following..

db.execSQL("delete from TABLE_NAME where COLUMN_ID="+value);

Comment: I think you miss read my question.. I want to delete nth row ... and you are suggesting a way to delete the row with column id=n

Comment: Don't you miss some '*' between DELETE and FROM ?

Comment: No, it's implicit for the DELETE command

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ( n+1 )th record by the following :

```
SELECT * FROM Students LIMIT 1 OFFSET n;
```

n is the index you're after starting with zero. So you can select the 2nd row by:

```
SELECT * FROM Students LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

You can also delete the second row by :

```
DELETE FROM Students WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM Students LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)
```